# Scheme Argument Checker Error-handling

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm fairly new to Scheme programming and was wondering how I can add some error checkers in this program. I would like it to check if the user types in more than one parameter and if the user does I would like it to say that its an error.

```
(define (thirds lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst))) lst)
        ((null? (cddr lst)) (list (car lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst)
                    (thirds (cdddr  lst))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scheme interpreter should check this automatically. You only need to do your own checking of the number of arguments if you define the procedure to take spread arguments, i.e.

```
(define (thirds . args)
  ...)
```

You would normally only do this if the procedure takes a variable number of arguments. For procedures with static arguments, just list them in the definition and let the interpreter do the checking for you.

If you really want to detect this yourself, you can do:

```
(define (thirds . args)
    (if (= (length args) 1)
        (let ((lst (car args)))
            (cond ... ; all the rest of your code
                ))
        (display "Oh that's an error")))
```

Comment: I tried it but I would like it to be able to take arguments such as "lista" when its previously defined. For example: (define lista (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g)) => (thirds lista) => (a d g)

Comment: I just checked that if I change the function into (define (thirds "." lst)...) It won't give me the right output. (thirds lista) => (a b c d e f g)

Comment: Why did you rewrite the function like that? Then you have to do `(apply thirds lista)`.

Comment: I never said to change the function. I said you only have to do argument checking IF you define the function like that. But since your function isn't written like that, and doesn't need to be, you don't have to do argument checking.

Comment: I see. Sorry bout that. When I enter it as it is, it throws the error saying it "exactly needs 1 argument" and "2 arguments has been called" I was wondering how I can catch that and print out something like "Oh thats an error" instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, using your definition of `thirds` in `#!racket` (the language) and trying to use it like this:

```
(thirds '(a b c) '(d e f))
thirds: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   '(a b c)
   '(d e f)
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

As you can see all computation stops since I have given a one argument procedure two arguments. It's a contract violation and it throws an [exception](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html).

It's perfectly possible to make handlers:

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail:contract?
                   (λ (e) (displayln "got a contract error"))])
    (thirds '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)))

; prints "got a contract error"
```